# sql query in python--debugging appending values

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle

I am trying to append certain values row[9:11] to my query results IF rows0-8 are already in existence (to avoid redundancy and move from many rows to one row, many columns).  The query executes fine, and if I remove the "else" clause, it works fine.  However, I'm not getting it to print the rows that already exist with the additional values (and I know these rows exist)... any ideas what I'm missing?

```
cursor.execute(query, cruise6_input=cruise6_input)
output=""
checkID=""
for row in cursor.fetchall():

    if row[0] != checkID:
        if output != "":
            print output, "this is a test"

        checkID=row[0]
        output=row[0:11]


    else:
        output=output + (row[8:11])
```

this printed all of the rows of original output and the "this is a test"...

Comment: Ok, I removed it but am still getting the same results...

Comment: `output` is commented out, so it has not been defined by the time you try to use it later in `output.join(str(row[8:11]))`. Also, `str(row[8:11])` will just return a string representation of a list. You should use `output = ','.join(str(x) for x in row[8:11])`.

Comment: are you sure that your else closes the correct if condition?

Comment: I just fixed that as well... however, I'm still getting the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My nesting was off.  Instead of:

```
if row[0] != checkID:
    if output != "":
        print output, "this is a test"

    checkID=row[0]
    output=row[0:11]


else:
    output=output + (row[8:11])
```

I had:

```
  if row[0] != checkID:
        if output != "":
            print output, "this is a test"

            checkID=row[0]
            output=row[0:11]


    else:
        output=output + (row[8:11])
```

Silly typos.  Thanks all!